# XML, XSLT select a specific group

Tags: xml, xslt

Been working on this for too long now.  Presidents is my root element and the list goes on through president number 45.  I need to only select presidents in the 21st century so > 41.  Can't seem to crack how to use the proper xsl to make that happen.

```
<presidents>
<president>
    <number>1</number>
    <name>George Washington</name>
    <date>
        2/22/1732
    </date>
    <took_office>April 30, 1789</took_office>
    <left_office>March 4, 1797</left_office>
    <party>no party</party>
    <term>
        <number>1</number>
        <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president>
    </term>
    <term>
        <number>2</number>
        <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president>
    </term>
</president>
```

In the following XSLT, I commented out the `<xsl:value-of` that I'm trying that is not working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="//president[number(@number)>41]/number"/>-->
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_21c.css"/>
            <title>Table of US Presidents</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Table of US Presidents</h1>
            <table border="2">
                <tr bgcolor="orange">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Birthday</th>
                    <th>Took Office</th>
                    <th>Left Office</th>
                    <th>Party</th>
                    <th>Picture</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="presidents/president"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select "presidents in the 21st Century" the actual expression you want is `number(substring-after(left_office, ', ')) >= 2000`. This assumes all your dates are of the same format; `MMM dd, yyyy`.

You can actually put your condition as part of the `xsl:apply-templates`

```
 <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="presidents/president[number(substring-after(left_office, ', ')) >= 2000]"/>
```

An alternate condition would be to get the last four characters of the date

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="presidents/president[number(substring(left_office, string-length(left_office) - 3)) >= 2000]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="presidents/president"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="presidents/president[number > 41]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the terminating `</presidents>` from your XML and the terminating `</xsl:stylesheet>` from your XSLT. Also, you appear to want to display a link to an image of each president but that isn't in your source XML.

If you want to discriminate based on the number, try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="//president[number(@number)>41]/number"/>-->
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_21c.css"/>
                <title>Table of US Presidents</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Table of US Presidents</h1>
                <table border="2">
                    <tr bgcolor="orange">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Birthday</th>
                        <th>Took Office</th>
                        <th>Left Office</th>
                        <th>Party</th>
                        <th>Picture</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="presidents/president">
                        <xsl:if test="number &gt;= 41">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="date" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="took_office" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="left_office" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="party" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry but forgot to mention I can't use for-each on this.